# Calling function with different argument C++

Tags: c++, performance, coding-style

This question is just for improvement purpose. There is a function below:

```
void Func_A(u8* arg) {
    bool local_arg=false;
    if(!arg) {
        //allocate memory for arg 
        local_arg=true;
    }
    //process arg
```

I am calling this function from multiple places with NULL and non NULL argument.
I just want to ask whther there is a better way of handling such this without local_arg or not.

Comment: It would help if you could describe whether `*arg` is an input and/or an output, and what `Func_A` is meant to accomplish if `arg` is NULL.

Comment: You could try a default argument for the function, but I'm not too sure if that will change much for your case.

Comment: `local_arg` isn't doing anything in your code. You should post a more realistic example.

Comment: arg is just an empty variable. In the process arg, I am reading from file in this arg. Local_arg is used to free the memory in the end.

Comment: You know, you can edit your question to add relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sometimes use...

```
u8* p = arg ? arg : new u8(...);

...do things with *p...

if (!arg) delete p;
```

A little fancier, you can write a smart pointer with runtime-configurable ownership:

```
template <typename T>
class Uncertain_Ownership_Ptr
{
  public:
    enum Ownership { Own_It, Dont_Own_It };
    Uncertain_Ownership_Ptr(T* p, Ownership own) : p_(p), own_(own) { }
    Uncertain_Ownership_Ptr(const Uncertain_Ownership_Ptr&) = delete;
    void operator=(const Uncertain_Ownership_Ptr&) = delete;
    ~Uncertain_Ownership_Ptr() { if (own_ == Own_It) delete p_; }
    T& operator*() { return *p_; }
    const T& operator*() const { return *p_; }
    T* operator->() { return p_; }
    const T* operator->() const { return p_; }
  private:
    T* p_;
    Ownership own_;
};
```

...then...

```
void Func_A(u8* arg)
{
    Uncertain_Ownership_Ptr p(arg ? arg : new u8(...),
        arg ? Uncertain_Ownership_Ptr::Dont_Own_It : Uncertain_Ownership_Ptr::Own_It);

    // use *p ...
}
```